# shell script: to compare 2 variables having values containing spaces

Tags: shell

I have 2 variables say

```
echo $a
[5] [2] [3]
echo $b
[9] [3] [2]
```

Many more to it. I want to compare both these variables.

```
do <1> if they are equal
do <2> if they are unequal
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. What did you try? And which shell are you using?  The key to the answer is to use double quotes around the variables — that works with all shells.  Some shells provide mechanisms to avoid using quotes — `bash` does, for example, with the `[[` operator.

Answer (score 2):

You want to compare `$a` and `$b` containing spaces. Use `if-then-else` and `double-quote` your variables:

```
if [ "$a" = "$b" ]; then
   echo '$a equals $b'
else
   echo '$a and $b differ'
fi
```

Comment: Isn't it just `=` to compare string equivalence?

Comment: `=` and `==` are equivalent in this context. You can use either one. `=` is POSIX compliant, `==` is unambiguous if you're coming from another language. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

Comment: It depends on the shell; orginal Bourne shell didn't use `==`; `bash` does.  I am not sure about `ksh` or `csh`.

Comment: Post edited for POSIX compliance and shell independence.